# como multiplicar un string por las veces que me dice una variable en Swift

Tags: swift, funciones, bucles

Hola lo que pasa es que no entiendo como multiplicar un string por el numero de veces que me diga una variable y almacenarlo en una función, me explico 6 es el numero de veces que se tiene que repetir y a! es el string  como hago para que quede a!a!a!a!a!a! ¿se tuviera que usar un bucle?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad en Swift no necesitarías usar ningún bucle solo crear la variable como menciona la [documentación de las cadenas en swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string). Algo así:

```
let cadena = String(repeating: "a!", count: 6)
print(cadena)
```

Ahora que si tuvieras una variable para cadena o para número solo necesitarías remplazar en el código, por ejemplo:

```
var x: Int = 6
var str: String = "a!"
let cadena = String(repeating: str, count: x)
print(cadena)
```